# iPhone UI Updating while Xcode paused at breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an odd UI bug I am tracking down, where my UI in a particular `UIViewController` subclass shows up *mostly* ok and then animates itself to be totally ok.

I have tracked down where the "shift" is occurring, but have not yet completely solved the issue. While attempting to track down and fix the bug, I had a very, very odd thing happen.

I set and hit a breakpoint in `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` for the `UIViewController` in question. When the breakpoint was hit, the UI on the attached phone was wrong. Then, while still on the breakpoint, without me taking any action, the UI performed the "shift" to correct the out-of-position frames.

How is this possible? Shouldn't `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` fire on the main/UI thread? If so, how is any adjustment being made to the UI while paused?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some UI code running on a background thread?

Comment: I guess not completely positive, but shouldn't Xcode throw warnings if I execute UI code on any thread but the main thread? I mean, in Xcode 9, if I even access `UIApplication` from another thread, it throws a runtime warning. And I do try to make all my UI updates on the main thread.